# "to find" for "to have an opinion"

Tags: word-usage

I think I've seen this before but I'm not sure if it is proper English: can I use "He finds XYZ a good thing" or whatever for "He approves of XYZ"?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It can mean that. Very old joke: Waiter: How did you find your steak, sir? Diner: I just moved my peas and there it was!

Comment: You can also say *He finds XYZ good.", without *a..thing*.

Comment: This idiom generally refers to "finding" something in a particular state or condition.  So you would not generally say "find something a good thing."  You can, however, say: "find something to be a good thing" to indicate the "state" or "condition" of the thing.

Comment: @vegawatcher - that isn't true. To find something good, delicious, funny, frightening, tedious, etc, is a perfectly normal usage.

Comment: I agree, but you wouldn't say ''find it a good deal," "find it a delicious snack, etc."  You are describing how you find it, not what you find it, unless you say what you find it to be.

Comment: @Vegawatcher I would say those things, e.g. "I have always found him a good worker and a good time keeper", "I found him a good teacher", "Mrs. Campbell soon lost the restraint her being a stranger had occasioned, and Mrs. Meridith found her a sensible, well-informed woman", all found in the last 90 seconds.

Comment: @Vegawatcher - ""But I talked with her this afternoon," I objected, "and I found her a sensible woman - remarkably bright for one of her years." - Jack London's novel, "Samuel". - "We really liked the idea of the land management plan and found it a useful way to help us see the potential our farms can deliver" - UK government web site.

Comment: I stand corrected about my narrow assertion.  Thank you for the follow up.  In my idiolect, If I say "I find her a sensible woman," I am stating more my general experience with her than my definitive opinion.  Stating the experience is, of course, a way of conveying an opinion, but for me it is just an implication.  The original poster's question was about approval.  To unequivocally state my approval of her in my idiolect, I would say "I find her to be a sensible woman"; whereas saying "I find her a sensible woman just states the evidence I have so far."

Comment: @Vegawatcher - in my main idiolect (UK English, slightly old-fashioned), "I find her to be a sensible woman" and "I find her a sensible woman" would be interchangeable, with the meaning "I have discovered, and currently perceive, her to be a sensible woman".

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'find' that way.

> find verb
>
> (EXPERIENCE A FEELING)   [ T ]
>
> to think or feel a particular way about someone or something:
>
> [ + obj + noun/adj ]
> *Do you find John difficult to talk to?
>
> I don't find him an easy person to get on with.
>
> She doesn't find it easy to talk about her
> problems.*
>
> [ + -ing verb ]
> *I find living in the city very stressful.*

[Find (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/find)

*I found her a sensible woman* Jack London (novel, 'Samuel', 1907)

*We really liked the idea of the land management plan and found it a useful way to help us see the potential our farms can deliver* - UK government web site, 2021.